# symfony 4 process running a command, not running

Tags: symfony4

I have a command called:

```
broker:create-device
```

It accepts 2 command line parameters. When I run via the command line it worked.

Now, I want to run from the controller. So I read in another Stack Overflow post I can do:

```
    $process = new Process(['php bin/console broker:create-device',1,2]);
    $process->run();
```

and that does execute the command, log shows a deprecation error only:

```
[2019-02-07 17:04:13] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use "Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command" with dependency injection instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Command\\ContainerAwareCommand\" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use \"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command\" with dependency injection instead. at /Users/myuser/Code/site/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php:18)"} []
```

But, the actual code in execute isn't running. Any ideas why?

Comment: I added ProcessFailedException, and the error says no such file. But its there. I even tried putting full path, /usr/bin/php /path/to/site/bin/console and it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

It seems every space needs to be separated, not just the arguements...

So the above process was edited to

$process = new Process(['php','bin/console','broker:create-device',1,2]);